# Assembly Language nasm error

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, shellcode

I have written the following assembly code as prescribed by my text book in the intel 64 bit syntax

```
Section .text
global _short
_start:
        jmp short    Gotocall
shellcode:
        pop             rcx
        xor             eax,eax
        mov byte        [rcx+8], al
        lea             rdi, [rax]
        mov long        [rcx+8], rdi
        mov long        [rcx+12], eax
        mov byte        al, 0x3b
        mov             rsi, rax
        lea             rdi, [esi+8]
        lea             edx, [esi+12]
        int             0x80

Gotocall:

        call            shellcode
        db              '/bin/shJAAAAKKKK'
```

but i get a nasm error in line 10 like this
asmshell.asm:10: error: mismatch in operand sizes
Can anybody tell me what mistake is their in my code.

And can anybody please tell me some good references to the 64 bit intel assembly instructions.

Comment: And how do you invoke `nasm`, how do you attempt to build your program?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i use this command nasm -f elf64 asmshell.asm

Comment: If your textbook advises `mov byte al, 0x3b` is it any good? What other size can `al` be?

Comment: Was it typo on your side, or typo in the book?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes that was unnecesary. I copied the code as it was in my book.

Comment: Note that this can't work as actual shellcode injected into stack memory; the int 0x80 ABI is 32-bit and will thus truncate pointers.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the error is on line 10

```
mov long [rcx+8], rdi
```

I was about to ask you what size `long` qualifier is, but the next line

```
mov long [rcx+12], eax
```

shows that you are moving two different sizes of register to the same size destination. In the first case the 64-bit register `rdi`, in the second case the 32-bit register `eax`, and `long` cannot satisfy them both.

Why not just drop the `long` since by specifying the register, the assembler knows the size of the destination? But sadly, you have only allowed 4 bytes memory to store a 64-bit register, given away by the `[rcx+8]` followed by `[rcx+12]`.

Perhaps you intended

```
mov long [rcx+8], edi
```

Comment: thanks @WeatherVane i corrected it and now it compiles smoothly. Assembly language can be frustating sometimes.